# INDI protocol with AZ GoTo SynScan to control an amateur telescope mount : problem with tracking

Tags: amateur-observing

I have a SkyWatcher telescope with an AZ mount and a SynScan GoTo to drive the telescope.

I want to drive the telescope from my computer.
Using Linux, I use the INDI protocol ([https://www.indilib.org](https://www.indilib.org/))  with the Kstars/Ekos software.

The problem is that, when I ask the system to track a specific RA/DEC coordinates point, the telescope slews but then stops tracking.
I have the same problem using `carte du ciel` instead of `Kstars`.

Here are some system specifications

- synscan version : 4.39.1
- indilib version : 1.8.3
- OS : Linux Debian 9

Has it happened to someone else?

Comment: Does it slew to the *correct* position?

Comment: Yes it does, but then it stops